# Prolog recursion overflow

Tags: recursion, prolog, clpfd, prolog-cut

```
fact(1,1):-!.
fact(N,F):-
    N1=N-1,
    fact(N1,F1),
    F=F1*N.
```

It leads to the stackoverflow(not the site)! It shouldn't because of the cut(!). Does it work in SWI-Prolog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that both definitions (the OP's and pad's) do not terminate for a query like `fact(0,N)`.  But also `fact(1,2)` does not terminate. It should fail. And for `fact(N, F)` it gives only one correct answer, but there should be infinitely many. Using cuts for such purpose is very tricky. The cleanest way to fix this is to add the goal `N > 0` to the rule and have a fact `fact(0,1).` There is an even better way, provided you use SWI-Prolog: Use `library(clpfd)`. In the documentation, you find `n_factorial/2` already defined. It can be used for queries like:

```
?- n_factorial(47, F).
   F = 258623241511168180642964355153611979969197632389120000000000
;  false.
?- n_factorial(N, 1).
   N = 0
;  N = 1
;  false.
?- n_factorial(N, 3).
   false.
```